# localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: hadoop

I have hadoop 3.0.0 stand alone working on Ubuntu 16.04 and converting to Suedo distributed and at the stage of running Master and salve Nodes using the comand

```
$ sudo /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

The results come up as

```
[sudo] password for tc: 
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 1: #: command not found
WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER has been replaced by HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER. Using value of HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 1: #: command not found
WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER has been replaced by HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER. Using value of HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER.
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 1: #: command not found
WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER has been replaced by HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER. Using value of HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER.
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [tc-ThinkCentre-M91p-Invalid-entry-length-16-Fixed-up-to-11]
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 1: #: command not found
WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER has been replaced by HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER. Using value of HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER.
tc-ThinkCentre-M91p-Invalid-entry-length-16-Fixed-up-to-11: Permission denied (publickey,password).
WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER has been replaced by HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER. Using value of HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER.
```

I can't understand why it's coming up saying;

localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).

when I have entered my root user password
I have set hadoop-env.sh up as;

```
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=hdfs 
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root 
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this message ?

> localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).

And should I be concerned with the

> hadoop-env.sh: line 1: #: command not found

Comment: How many ubuntu machines are you using in this setup?

Comment: Additionally can you check if "PasswordAuthentication" parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is set to "yes"

Comment: Line 1 of those scripts would be trying to load bash, I believe... Not sure why that's throwing an error

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wanting to run Psuedo distributed one on machine